# Access web server over https in a Docker container

Tags: https, docker, portforwarding, boot2docker

I'm using Boot2Docker to manage Docker containers in Windows and I have a container running an IBM Liberty server (I guess is the same for any other server), I can access the server home screen in the host machine using only the ip (which I get using the command `boot2docker ip`), but if I try to access the server using the `https` port, like this `xx.xx.xx.xx:9443` the connection fails.

I tried forwarding the port in VirtualBox like this:
[image]

And then access the server using the ports `1000` or `1001`, but it fails too.

Am I missing something?

BTW, I'm using default NAT connection.

Answer (score 0):

`https` uses port `443` (not `9443`) by default.

Make both "Host Port" and "Guest Port" 443 and try again.